# "Select All" in Table is now sending too much data to Server via API - Alternative Ways to Send to Server?

Tags: architecture, javascript, reactjs, stream-processing, apache-kafka

**Outline of the current architecture of our web app outlining the issue I'm seeing**

Client-side app is React, talking to a server running the Play! framework via an API.

On the page is a table that allows a user to select 0 to many rows via checkboxes. There are buttons above the table that allow the user to take bulk actions on all the currently checked rows.

Example: The table shows 9 rows in the table. The user selects rows 1, 2, and 9. The user then presses the "Restart Server" button. A POST API call is made to the server with the payload of [1, 2, 9].

**Overview of Issue**

This has worked fine to date, but now we have several tables in our application that have thousands or even tens of thousands of rows. The tables are paginated. A common use case we've seen from clients is that they'll press the "Select All" button and then go through pages unselecting rows, and then press an Action button.

Sending this array of selected rows isn't working with our API though and causing errors due to its sheer size. The Play! framework (according to the API engineer) allocates X amount of memory for each request, where X is a preset amount. That amount would need to be increased to handle the size of the request, but the side effect is that it would allocate that memory for every request, causing memory issues under medium or heavy load. As a result, the API can't change.

So the root of the problem is that the client side needs to send a huge array of table_row_ids to the server, but the server can only process a set amount of rows, and it throws an error when the array.length > max_rows_allowed_to_server.

**Needed Solution**

I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to keep the API server unchanged, and all software related changes would happen in the client-side code.  I think the problem breaks down into 2 sections.  1) How to determine when the request *can't* go to the server because of the size of the payload and 2) How to serve data (table rows) to the server in a size and pace it can handle.

For problem #1, I can envision some kind of interceptor code in our API layer that would re-route traffic given a certain number of rows in the array.  I have concerns it may be too specific if we have JS code like `if (data.rows && data.rows.length > 100)` so is there a cleaner, more general way to flag these types of requests?

For problem #2, I'm more at a loss. I had originally thought of spinning off a WebWorker "thread" that would loop through the table rows, sending X rows to the server every Y seconds.  But that has obvious faults, like losing internet connection during the process.  Is there a better architecture solution on the client side for this? A React library I'm missing?  Or even a 3rd party tool that simply does these kind of "spread out large requests to shorter chunks"?

Comment: From reading your thoughts, it seems you might be over-complicating things, but tell me if I'm missing something.
It sounds like what you want to do is break up your request into batches. The API can only handle a limited number of items in each request, so figure out a sensible batch size based on a number of items that you know to work. Split your array of items into multiple smaller arrays of size X and send each in a separate request to the server. And if you need to do something with the response, gather the many responses together and work with it as one object again.
One thing you'll ne

Comment: @LikeLikeAteMyShield Please avoid using Answers to request clarification on a Question.  This is what comments should be used for.

Comment: @maple_shaft If you actually read the rest of what I wrote I also provided an answer based on what has been provided in the question. I didn't really ask for clarification, just inviting feedback from OP in case I've made incorrect assumptions about the problem.
I wonder sometimes how anyone gets answers on this site when people only seem to care about the semantics of how to use the site, rather than actually helping people.

Answer (score 0):

From a client-side fix perspective, you'd simply want to chunk up the data to be POST-ed beyond a certain size.

Example code, without async / await since it's not doing any async work, just keep in mind that yours will (should?) be, hope this helps!

```
const submitRows = (rows) => {
    //your current implementation to POST data to the server
    console.log(`POSTing ${rows.length} rows to server: ${rows}`);
}
// if you don't need to do anything else with the data, you can just submit the slices, 
// instead of pushing them to an intermediary array
const maxChunkSize = 10;
let testArray = Array(101).fill(1);
let resultArray = []
for (i = 0; i*maxChunkSize < testArray.length; i++) {
    resultArray.push(testArray.slice(i*maxChunkSize, (i+1)*maxChunkSize));
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(resultArray));
resultArray.forEach(chunk=>submitRows(chunk));
```